# Java Polymorphic Json Deserialization

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

I am using jackson as part of serializing and deserializing in my project (Spring Java).
In normal scenarios where I have interface(contract) acting as field in POJO,
then I use `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes` to achieve deserialization in polymorphic cases.
But, right now, I have scenariio something like this:

```
public class classA {

    private contractA fieldA;
    
    //constructor and getter-setters.
}
```

then,

```
public interface contractA {
}
```

and finally,

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(/* concrete-class1 as name-value */),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(/* concrete-class2 as name-value */),
})
public interface contractB extends contractA {
    //contract methods.
}
```

Now, when `classA` is passed as controller request body and I pass `fieldA` as `concrete-class1` or `concrete-class2`,
`JsonSubTypes` are not being used by jackson to deserialize into one of them.
The reason why I did this and had two contracts is due to package dependencies. `contractB`
is in different package as of `contractA`'s.
How can I configure on `contractA` using jackson that this class has its `JsonSubTypeInfo` specified in its subclasses.

Or, any other libraries or approaches are also welcomed.

Thank you !

Comment: Try to declare `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes` annotations over `ContractA` interface using [MixIn](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations) feature. See [Jackson parse json with unwraping root, but without ability to set @JsonRootName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568867/jackson-parse-json-with-unwraping-root-but-without-ability-to-set-jsonrootname)

Comment: Something similar answer I wrote here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63620373/3295987

Comment: @PratapiHemantPatel I have `classA` and `contractA` in different package, say `package1`. And `contractB` in different package, say `package2`. And, `package2` has dependency of `package1`. So, I cannot refer `package2` classes in `package1`. And `concrete-class1`(and `concrete-class2`) are in `package2`. So, I cannot refer them as `@JsonSubTypes` on `contractA`, however I can refer them on `contractB`, that's why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is later on solved by introducing our own custon `JsonTypeInfo`.

When the application is under deployment, we fetch all subclasses which is present in the `JsonTypeInfo` annotation (jackson like custom annotaion) and maintain a data-structure, that will be used while `serializing` and `deserializing`. This process is somewhat similar to the `Jackson` one (in addition to lookup for nested hierarches as well).